# How do I write a Wye symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I am writing a technical document in LaTeX and it involves using ANSI Electrical symbols for transformer connections. The greek letter Delta work for using half of what I need, however I still require a way to write a Wye/[Grounded-Wye](https://testguy.net/content/219-Electrical-One-Line-Diagram-Symbols?s=d215ab8bc1f1eb627d1f513f800426a3) symbol:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `tikz-circuit` provides something like that symbol

Comment: I checked tikz-circuit and there was only a Ground symbol, no Wye/Grounded-Wye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol can be drawn with TikZ (also LaTeX's environment `picture` could be used).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[x=1pt, y=1pt, scale=2]\draw
    (-1.8, 0) -- (1.8, 0)
    (-1.2, -1) -- (1.2, -1)
    (-0.6, -2) -- (0.6, -2)
    (0, 0) -- ++(0, 3) -- ++(2.5, 0) coordinate (tmp)
    -- +(0, -2)
    (tmp) +(45:2) -- (tmp) -- +(135:2)
  ;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Perfect! To get exactly what worked for me, I was able to pull something together using this: '\tikz[x=1pt, y=1pt, scale=2]\draw
    (3, -1.8) -- (3, 1.8)
    (4, -1.2) -- (4, 1.2)
    (5, -0.6) -- (5, 0.6)
    (3, 0) -- (0, 0) coordinate (tmp)
    -- +(0, -3)
    (tmp) +(45:3) -- (tmp) -- +(135:3)
    ;'